# What to do when a newcomer is begging for unclosing a question?

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions, etiquette

I'm in a conflict with the asker of a certain question about writing tutorials for Mozilla: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239910/how-to-write-tutorials-for-programming-sites

Together with some other people, I have closed this question as being Off Topic, as it is.
However, OP begs for an unclose. What should I do/say? Seems he doesn't care if someone closes it except for when I do :/

Comment: After becoming aware of this one I closed and deleted his original question (which was a dupe and way off the beaten path for any SE site). I did leave a comment explaining the error of his ways but you just can't tell some users some of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question has been closed after 5 users voted to close the question, which is the higher number of users required to close a question; it has not been the decision taken from two users.
In both the cases, if a question has been wrongly closed, 5 users (or less, if one of the users is a moderator) can vote to re-open the question; the OP can vote to re-open his/her question too.

Begging any of the users who closed the question to re-open it is needless; any user who can vote to close a question can also vote to re-open it (and they don't need to be the same users).

I would say don't say anything. If you think that effectively the question should have not been closed, or you changed your mind (e.g. because you are now giving the question a different interpretation), then you can vote to re-open it.